# Can `sed` replace 5th and 7th spaces in each line with a single `s/` substitute command?

Tags: sed

I can replace only the 5th and 7th spaces with the command:

```
$ echo "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8" | sed 's/\ /x/5;s/\ /x/6'
1 2 3 4 5x6 7x8
```

but does maybe `sed` support lists and ranges of *n*th pattern occurrences to use just one substitute `s/` instead of the two separated by semicolons?

```
$ echo "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8" | sed 's/\ /x/5,7'
sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unknown option to `s'
```

Comment: only range of **line** numbers

Comment: If you do the 7th and then the 5th, you don't have to adjust the numbers.

Answer (score 3):

With shells with `csh`-like brace expansion (csh, tcsh, zsh, bash, pdksh, ksh93, `yash -o braceexpand`, `fish`), you could do:

```
$ echo 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 | sed '-es/ /x/'{7,6,5}
1 2 3 4 5x6x7x8 9
```

Brace expansion expands that to

```
sed '-es/ /x/'7 '-es/ /x/'6 '-es/ /x/'5
```

We're doing it backwards so that one substitution has no influence on the next one.

You can make it a range with the `{x..y}` form from `zsh` (now also supported by bash, ksh93, `yash -o braceexpand`)

```
$ echo 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 | sed '-es/ /x/'{7..3}
1 2 3x4x5x6x7x8 9
```

or combinations of both forms:

```
$ echo 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 | sed '-es/ /x/'{{7..3},1}
1x2 3x4x5x6x7x8 9
```

With `zsh`, you can put those in an array:

```
$ substs=({7..5} 3 1)
$ echo 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 | sed '-es/ /x/'$^substs
1x2 3x4 5x6x7x8 9
```

And have `zsh` sort them in the correct reverse numerical order:

```
$ substs=(1 8 6)
$ echo 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 | sed '-es/ /x/'${(On)^substs}
1x2 3 4 5 6x7 8x9
```

With `zsh` or `bash`, you can also do:

```
$ substs=({7..5} 3 1)
$ echo 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 | sed "${substs[@]/#/-es: :x:}"
1x2 3x4 5x6x7x8 9
```

With `fish` (and GNU `seq`), you can do things like:

```
$ echo 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 | sed '-es/ /x/'(seq 6 -1 3)
1 2 3x4x5x6x7 8 9
```

Or:

```
$ set substs 5 3 1
$ echo 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 | sed '-es/ /x/'$substs
1x2 3x4 5x6 7 8 9
```

(`fish` arrays expand like in `rc` or `zsh -o rcexpandparam` in this instance).

---

With `perl`, you could do something like:

```
$ echo 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 | perl -pe 'BEGIN{$h{$_}=1 for (3,5..8)}
                                     my $n; s/ /$h{++$n} ? "x" : $&/ge'
1 2 3x4 5x6x7x8x9
```

Comment: I found that the range should be always `{max#..min#}` as well as numbers range in `{x,y,z}` shold be `x>y>z` and `{x,x}` if same numbers will cause a problem (BTW for this there is `s/ /x/X` alternative where `X` is position number).

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
$ set -- 6 7 # or bash -s 6 7 (set positional parameters)
$ echo "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8" | sed "s/ /x/$1"
1 2 3 4 5 6x7 8
$ shift # ¹
$ echo "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8" | sed "s/ /x/$1"
1 2 3 4 5 6 7x8
```

¹ :

> $ help shift
>   shift: shift [n]
>      Shift positional parameters.
>
> Rename the positional parameters $N+1,$N+2 ... to $1,$2 ...  If N is
>      not given, it is assumed to be 1.
>
> Exit Status:
>      Returns success unless N is negative or greater than $#

Comment: Why create array `arr` at all? Why not just `set -- 6 7`?

Comment: Improved snippet, thanks and added explanations