# How to change a range of instances of a string

Tags: text-processing

I need to change some instances of a sub-string on every line of a text file. These instances are all consecutive such as 3 to 6 or 2 to 5 etc. What command do I need for this operation? The nearest I got was:

```
sed 's/this/that/3' file1
```

which changes only the third occurrence. I was hoping that something like

```
sed 's/this/that/3,6' file1
```

could be the answer, but `sed` does not have occurrence range.

Example input:

```
I want to change all letters "a" to "w" starting from the word "all" until the second "all" (inclusive)
```

Expected output:

```
I want to change wll letters "w" to "w" stwrting from the word "wll" until the second "all" (inclusive)
```

Comment: Kludgy, but.... `sed 's/this/that/6' file1 | sed 's/this/that/5' | sed 's/this/that/4' | sed 's/this/that/3'`

Comment: similar in the [Stéphane Chazelas's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/432997/72456), you could do `sed '-es/this/that/'{6..3}`.

Comment: This is exactly what I was after. Thank you $afshin for this link; and thank you $Stéphane Chazelas. Sorry I am unable to upvote (as I am a mere amoeba as a new member).

Comment: Hang on - are you trying to change the 3rd to 6th character `a` on each line or every `a` from the 1st to 2nd string `all` on each line? They're very different questions with different answers required but you say both things in your question.

Comment: Changing 3rd to 6th character a on each line is what I want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably not possible with `sed`, but the following GNU `awk` program would work:

```
awk -v frst=2 -v lst=5 '{for (i=1; i<=(lst-frst+1);i++) $0=gensub(/a/,"w",frst)}1'
```

- This will pass the first and last occurences to replace as variables `frst` and `lst` to `awk`.
- It will then use `gensub()` to replace the `frst`-th occurence of the search pattern on the line, and assign the result back to the current line buffer.
- This will be done a total of (`lst-frst+1`) times to replace all desired occurences. Afterwards, the current line (including all modifications) are printed.
- Note that the number of the occurence within the string to replace always stays the same, because the already replaced occurences are no longer counted in the next loop iteration.

An application example:

```
$ echo "a1a2a3a4a5a6" | awk -v frst=2 -v lst=5 '{for (i=1; i<=(lst-frst+1);i++) $0=gensub(/a/,"w",frst)}1'
a1w2w3w4w5a6
```

or your original:

```
$ echo 'I want to change all letters "a" to "w" starting from the word "all" until the second "all" (inclusive)' | awk -v frst=3 -v lst=6 '{for (i=1; i<=(lst-frst+1);i++) $0=gensub(/a/,"w",frst)}1'
I want to change wll letters "w" to "w" stwrting from the word "wll" until the second "all" (inclusive)
```

As usual, this will not work as expected if the search patterns can overlap.

Comment: That is a clever use of gensub, thanks. I never thought I would have any use for gensub!

Answer (score 4):

With `perl`:

Change third to sixth `a`s to `b`s:

```
$ echo aaaaaaaaa | perl -pe '$n=0; s{a}{++$n;$n==3..$n==6?"b":$&}ge'
aabbbbaaa
```

That uses the `e` flag to the `s{regex}{replacement}flags` operator so the replacement is evaluated as code which here gives `"b"` if an incremented counter is between 3 and 6 and what was matched (`$&`) otherwise. Alternatively:

```
$ echo aaaaaaaa | perl -pe '$n=0; s/a(?(?{++$n; $n == 3 .. $n == 6})|(*FAIL))/b/g'
aabbbbaa
```

Uses a `(?(condition)yes|no)` regex operator that gives `(*FAIL)` if the incremented counter is not in 3 .. 6 range.

GNU `sed` supports `s/foo/bar/3g` to replace the 3<sup>rd</sup> and following occurrences of `foo`.

So for fixed strings like that, you could do:

```
$ echo aaaaaaaaa | sed 's/a/\n/3g;s/\n/a/5g;s/\n/b/g'
aabbbbaaa
```

That is, replace the 3<sup>rd</sup> to last `a` with newline (guaranteed not to occur otherwise in the pattern space), then restore the 5<sup>th</sup> to last newlines back to `a`s (6 - 3 + 1 = 4 is the number of `a`s we want to replace, so restore the ones after), then replace all the remaining newlines with `b`s.

With any `sed`:

```
sed 's/a/\
/g
s/\n/b/3
s/\n/b/3
s/\n/b/3
s/\n/b/3
s/\n/a/g'
```

---

To change the `a`s to `w`s between the first two occurrences of `all`:

```
$ echo aaallaaallaaa | perl -pe 's{all.*?all}{$& =~ s/a/w/gr}e'
aawllwwwllaaa
```

Use the `\b` word boundary operators if the `all` must be delimited *words*.

```
$ echo 'alloy (all-hands aaa ball all) fall' | perl -pe 's{all.*?all}{$& =~ s/a/w/gr}e'
wlloy (wll-hands aaa ball all) fall
$ echo 'alloy (all-hands aaa ball all) fall' | perl -pe 's{\ball\b.*?\ball\b}{$& =~ s/a/w/gr}e'
alloy (wll-hwnds www bwll wll) fall
```

(add `-Mopen=locale` for characters to be decoded as per the locale charmap instead of assuming they're just ASCII and for instance recognise a UTF-8 encoded `allée` as one French word and not `all` followed by some non-word character).

Answer (score 2):

With any awk:

```
awk -v FS='a' -v start=3 -v end=6 -v replace="w" '
{
  for(i=1; i<NF; i++)
      printf("%s", $i (start<=i && i<=end? replace: FS))
  print $NF
}' infile
```

Here with the `FS=a` we are telling awk to split the records on the character `a`; we also defined other awk variables as *start*, *end* and *replace* for the start and end positions of the target character 'a' respectively, which we will replace it with 'w' character.

then we loop over the fields and print fields itself followed by replace character if field number was between start and end points or character 'a' if it was not in that range. finally we output the last field too.

[Run code snippet](https://awk.js.org/?snippet=KdBMjj)

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk for the 3rd arg to `match()`:

```
$ echo 'I want to change all letters "a" to "w" starting from the word "all" until the second "all" (inclusive)' |
awk -v b=3 -v e=6 -v o=a -v n=w '
    match($0,"(([^"o"]*"o"[^"o"]*){"b-1"})(("o"[^"o"]*){"e-b"}"o")(.*)",t) {
        gsub(o,n,t[3])
        $0 = t[1] t[3] t[5]
    }
    { print }
'
I want to change wll letters "w" to "w" stwrting from the word "wll" until the second "all" (inclusive)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
~$ echo aaaaaaaa | perl6 -pe 's:nth(3..6)/a/b/;'
aabbbbaa
```

Raku (a programming language in the Perl-family) has a new `nth` regex modifier ("positional adverb"), which enables synonyms like `1st`, `2nd`, `3rd`, etc. For general replacement use `nth()`, inserting a numeric or range argument.

Above is the quick version. Below is only to demonstrate how intuitive this aspect of Raku regex-modifiers can be (`6th`, `5th`, `4th`, `3rd` matches get substituted consecutively, each time using `andthen` to reload the `$_` topic variable):

```
~$ echo aaaaaaaa | perl6 -ne 'S:6th/a/b/ andthen S:5th/a/b/ andthen S:4th/a/b/ andthen S:3rd/a/b/ andthen .put;'
aabbbbaa
```

https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Positional_adverbs
https://raku.org